# Understanding addresses of Swift array elements

Tags: swift

I've been looking at the addresses of Swift array elements and I'm surprised by the results. Here's my code for Bool elements:

```
let boolArray = [false, true, false, true]
withUnsafePointer(to: boolArray[0]) { print($0) }
withUnsafePointer(to: boolArray[1]) { print($0) }
```

Here are the printed results:

```
0x000000016fdff40e
0x000000016fdff40c
```

It looks like the first element is stored two bytes *after* the second. Bizarre.

Here's my code for Float elements:

```
let floatArray: [Float] = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4]
withUnsafePointer(to: floatArray[0]) { print($0) }
withUnsafePointer(to: floatArray[1]) { print($0) }
```

Here are the printed results:

```
0x000000016fdff408
0x000000016fdff400
```

Now the first value is stored eight bytes after the second. Just to check, here's another way to access memory locations:

```
withUnsafePointer(to: numArray) {
    print($0)
    print($0.advanced(by: 1))
}
```

Here are the printed results:

```
0x000000016fdff418
0x000000016fdff420
```

This time, the first element is before the second, but they're separated by eight bytes. The array contains Floats, so I'd expected the second address to be four bytes after the first.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried looking at the source code but it does not make any sense to me :). https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/7123d2614b5f222d03b3762cb110d27a9dd98e24/stdlib/public/core/ArrayBuffer.swift. My intuition is that you **can't** assume that Swift arrays will handle data like C arrays do

Comment: By the way, `Array` does not guarantee that elements are contiguous. They are most of the time, except for when interoperating with `NSArray`. And new use-cases might come up in the future where it's non-contiguous.

Comment: `boolArray[0]` does not point into the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Case 1

You're printing the addresses of temporary values that you're getting as a result of subscripting the array. Try passing the value as a reference, instead:

```
var boolArray = [false, true, false, true]
withUnsafePointer(to: &boolArray[0]) { print($0) }
withUnsafePointer(to: &boolArray[1]) { print($0) }

var floatArray: [Float] = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4]
withUnsafePointer(to: &floatArray[0]) { print($0) }
withUnsafePointer(to: &floatArray[1]) { print($0) }
```

## Case 2

When you do this:

```
withUnsafePointer(to: numArray) {
    print($0)
    print($0.advanced(by: 1))
}
```

You're getting the address of the `Array`, not the buffer of the `Array`. The pointer type is `UnsafePointer<Array<Float>>`, *not* `UnsafePointer<Float>`, which is probably what you were expecting. You can confirm this with `print(type(of: $0))`.

When you advance this pointer by "1", you're advancing it by `MemoryLayout<Array<Float>>.stride` (which is 8 bytes on 64 bit Intel). That stride is the same regardless of the array's `Element` type (from what I can tell), but of course, don't rely on that detail. What you end up with is some piece of stack space just adjacent to your array. It does *not* look up the second float within the array.

To achieve what I think you were going for, you would use [`Array.withUnsafeBufferPointer(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994771-withunsafebufferpointer), or one of the other similar APIs of `Array`:

```
floatArray.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
    print(type(of: $0)) // UnsafeBufferPointer<Float>
    print($0.baseAddress!)
    print($0.baseAddress!.advanced(by: 1)) // 4 byte offset
}
```

Remember that `Array` is really just a struct which contains a pointer to a heap allocated buffer. All the elements are in that buffer, so if you're looking to poke around the memory, you need to look at the buffer, not the struct.

Comment: So where is this buffer? how do I find it ? (I mean the pointer) where to find the pointer in array struct we read array struct as bytes

Comment: There’s no exposed API for it. You can only get temporary, scoped access to it with the `withUnsafe…Pointer` APIs, like I showed. There are multiple storage strategies (e.g. for fast bridging to NSArray without copying elements). What exactly are you trying to do? Perhaps you should open a new question. Feel free to comment it here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `floatArray[n]` does not point into the array. To satisfy yourself, you could slice into the array:

```
let floatArray: [Float] = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4]
floatArray.withUnsafeBufferPointer { ptr in
    print(ptr.baseAddress)
}
floatArray[1...].withUnsafeBufferPointer { ptr in
    print(ptr.baseAddress)
}
```

Once you are satisfied with that, you will see that you can walk the memory directly (i.e. it gives the same answer):

```
floatArray.withUnsafeBufferPointer { ptr in
    print(ptr.baseAddress)
    print(ptr.baseAddress?.advanced(by: 1))
}
```